# Why specify a method twice - Java

Tags: java, function, class, definition

I am a python coder but recently started a forey into Java. I am trying to understand a specific piece of code but am running into difficulties which I believe are associated with not knowing Java too well, yet.

Something that stood out to me is that sometimes inside class definitions methods are called twice. I am wondering why that is? For example:

The following code is taken from a file called ApplicationCreator.java. I noticed that the public class ApplicationCreator essentially instantiates itself twice, or am I missing something here?

```
public class ApplicationCreator<MR> implements
    IResourceObjectCreator<BinaryRuleSet<MR>> {

private String  type;

public ApplicationCreator() {
    this("rule.application");
}

public ApplicationCreator(String type) {
    this.type = type;
}
```

So here my questions:

1) Why would the class instantiate itself inside the class?

2) Why would it do so twice? Or is this a way to set certain parameters of the ApplicationCreator class to new values?

Any advice would be highly appreciated.

Comment: These are called constructors.  One takes a parameter and the other doesn't.  The one that does then use a hard coded value to construct itself by calling the other constructor.  As another `new` keyword is not used, only one Object is instantiated

Comment: Oh. Ok so in this example, does that mean that depending on whether I instantiate the class with no arguments or with one argument (type) the code would execute the first or second constructor respectively?

Comment: This is called "overloading", and refers to the ability to define a constructor or method multiple times but with different parameters. The number and type of the parameters when calling the method determines which method is called.

Comment: @Z101 Yes, exactly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Why would the class instantiate itself inside the class?

> The class is not calling itself, it is proving a way for others to instantiate its object. Read about [constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html).

2) Why would it do so twice? Or is this a way to set certain parameters of the ApplicationCreator class to new values?

> As I said, it is a way to create object. 1st one will assign default value to type. And 2nd will give others an option to assign a value. Read about [constructor overloading](http://beginnersbook.com/2013/05/constructor-overloading/).

`this` in the constructor will call another constructor of the same class depending upon argument type passed to [this](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiy59_vvfzOAhVBqY8KHe8kAd0QFggeMAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fjavabeginnerstutorial.com%2Fcore-java-tutorial%2Fthis-keyword-in-java%2F&usg=AFQjCNEreh7rKcCt7xagztPRByWuDwyubw&bvm=bv.131783435,d.c2I).

Answer (score 4):

It's not instantiating itself in the class, it's calling a different constructor in the class.

What these are are overloaded constructors. Constructors are somewhat method-like, but they are called on object creation. Consider this:

```
public class Example {
    private int instanceVariable;

    public Example() { //a constructor of Example
        instanceVariable = 3;
        System.out.println("New Example object was created!");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Example ex = new Example();
    }
}
```

Here, we have an `Example` class which has a constructor. If you look in the `main` method, we create a new instance of `Example`. The program will output `New Example object was created!` and set the instance's `instanceVariable` to 3 because the constructor is immediately called on object *as it constructs the object* (hence the name).

Now if you take a look at your situation, the constructors have different arguments (and thus signatures) so the object can be constructed by giving no arguments, or supplying a String. Let me illustrate what this does:

```
public ApplicationCreator() {
    this("rule.application");
}
```

`this` refers to the class in this case, and invoking `this(args)` calls a constructor of the class. Since we have overloaded constructors, Java will call the constructor that matches most closely to the passed arguments. Since, in this case, a String is passed, Java will see that the constructor `public ApplicationCreator(String)` is the one that matches most and will invoke it.

Inside the no-argument constructor, it calls the other constructor with String `rule.application`, so you can think of the no-argument constructor as passing a default value to the constructor taking in a String.

Answer (score 2):

These are two different constructors.
They have what is refered to as "different signatures.

Using it you can construct a  `ApplicationCreator` object in two different ways :

```
ApplicationCreator ac = new ApplicationCreator();
```

Or

```
ApplicationCreator ac = new ApplicationCreator("A String");
```

For further reading see: [The Java Class Constructor](http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/java/class_constructor.html)

Answer (score 1):

The class is really not instantiating itself twice.  Rather, the default constructor `ApplicationCreator()` (i.e. the one which takes no parameters), is simply calling the constructor which accepts an input string.

This ensures that an `ApplicationCreator` object will always have a type.  When a type is not specified the default value `rule.application` will be used.

This is an example of overloaded constructors.

Answer (score 0):

It's called a constructor. And it's not "called twice", one simply redirects to the other via `this()` with the given parameters.

Essentially the first way, without parameters, simply has a default value. Otherwise, you construct an instance with the given `String type`

Answer (score 0):

Here this class has two constructor. 

When class name "method" name are same you can understand those are constructor.

Here constructor is over loaded . Based on parameter classes will be instantiated. Here user have a choice based on need .